# minimum distance between 2d and 3 d curves

Tags: 3d

Let $P(x,y,1)$ and $Q(x,y,z)$ lies on the curve $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=4$ and $\displaystyle \frac{x+2}{1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-y}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{z-1}{2}$ respectively. Then the square of minimum distance between $P$ and $Q$ is

process i try

parametric coordinate for ellipse is $\displaystyle x = 6\cos \theta,y=4\sin \theta$

and line is $x=\lambda-2,y=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3}\lambda,z=2\lambda+1$

how do i solve it help me

Comment: Note that $\frac{x^2}9+\frac{y^2}4=1$ defines an elliptic cylinder, not a curve.

Comment: Are you asserting $P$ and $Q$ have the same $x$ and $y$ coordinates?